# Java Algorithm Animator/Visualisation

Tags: java, animation, visualization, string-matching

I am trying to create an algorithm animator which should look exactly like [this](http://whocouldthat.be/visualizing-string-matching/). I am wondering if anyone is aware of any packages, APIS that could be helpful/ allow me to do this in JAVA. I am currently using Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JAVAFX. Really nice library for animations etc. Also really good for implementing the MVP design. A very good tutorial exists [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLkOX4Eez6o)